# What is the difference between "Real Types" and "Arithmetic Types" in C?

Tags: c, types, c99

The C99 standard describes them as so:

> The integer and real floating types
>   are collectively called real types.
>
> Integer and floating types are
>   collectively called arithmetic types.

Does this mean they're the same thing in C? Or are there any differences between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complex types are arithmetic types, but not real types.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't careful in my reading. I misread "Real Floating Types" and "Floating Types", which are two different things. D'oh! Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

From ISO C 99 6.2.5 18:

> Integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types. Each arithmetic type
>   belongs to one type domain: the real type domain comprises the real types, the complex
>   type domain comprises the complex types.